Improving runtime on Pattern matching with most k mismatches
I am trying to improve the runtime of a runtime of the pattern matching problem with most k mismatches. My approach is heavily inspired from this question, which is to slide the pattern "window" throughout the text and count the number of mismatches between the pair by using binary search and rolling hash structure. Here is the original statement:
Task: For an integer parameter  and two strings  = 01 · · · −1 and  = 01 · · · −1, we say that  occurs in  at position  with at most  mismatches if the strings  and [ :  + ) = +1 · · · +−1 differ in at most  positions.
Input Format: Every line of the input contains an integer  and two strings  and  consisting of lower case Latin letters.
Constraints: 0 ≤  ≤ 5, 1 ≤ || ≤ 200 000, 1 ≤ || ≤ min{||, 100 000}. The total length of all ’s does not exceed 200 000, the total length of all ’s does not exceed 100 000.
Output Format: For each triple (, , ), find all positions 0 ≤ 1 < 2 < · · · <  < || where  occurs in  with at most  mismatches. Output  and 1, 2, . . . , .
My code:
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class matching_with_mismatches {
    private static int prime = 2000000033;
    private static int multiplier = 19;

    private long[] prefixHashT;
    private long[] prefixHashP;

    public List<Integer> solve(int k, String text, String pattern) {
        ArrayList<Integer> pos = new ArrayList<>();

        int tLen = text.length();
        int pLen = pattern.length();

        prefixHashT = new long[tLen + 1];
        prefixHashP = new long[pLen + 1];

        // Compute the hashes for prefixes
        prefixHashT[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= text.length(); i++) {
            prefixHashT[i] = (prefixHashT[i - 1] * multiplier + text.charAt(i - 1)) % prime;
        }

        prefixHashP[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= pattern.length(); i++) {
            prefixHashP[i] = (prefixHashP[i - 1] * multiplier + pattern.charAt(i - 1)) % prime;
        }

        // For each pair of p and substring of t
        for (int i = 0; i <= tLen - pLen; i++) {

            int start = i; // index of "text"
            int end = i + pLen - 1; // index of "text"
            int misMatches = 0;
            
            // Perform at most k binary searches for mismatches
            while (start <= end) {
                int mid = (start + end) / 2;

                long pSubHash = hashSubstring(prefixHashP, start - i, mid - i);
                long tSubHash = hashSubstring(prefixHashT, start, mid);

                if (pSubHash == tSubHash) { // Match
                    start = mid + 1;
                } else if (start == end) { // Pinpoint the mismatch aka mid
                    start = mid + 1;
                    end = i + pLen - 1;
                    if (++misMatches > k) break;
                } else { // Hashes don't match, but there may be mismatch before this mid
                    end = mid;
                }
            }
            
            if (misMatches > k) continue;
            else pos.add(i);
        }

        return pos;
    }

    public long hashSubstring(long[] prefixHash, int start, int end) throws RuntimeException {
        if (start < 0 || end + 1 > prefixHash.length) throw new RuntimeException("start and end must be within prefix length");

        start++;
        end++;

        int len = end - start + 1;
        if (len < 0) throw new RuntimeException("length must be positive");

        long y = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(multiplier))
            .modPow(new BigInteger(Integer.toString(len)), new BigInteger(Integer.toString(prime)))
            .longValue(); // (multiplier ^ len) % prime

        return ((prefixHash[end] - prefixHash[start - 1] * y) % prime + prime) % prime;
    }

    public void run() {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        in.lines().forEach(line -> {
            StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(line);
            int k = Integer.valueOf(tok.nextToken());
            String s = tok.nextToken();
            String t = tok.nextToken();
            List<Integer> ans = solve(k, s, t);
            out.format("%d ", ans.size());
            out.println(ans.stream()
                    .map(n -> String.valueOf(n))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
            );
        });
        out.close();
    }

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        new matching_with_mismatches().run();
    }
}

The problem states that the solution for this problem should run in O(nk.log(n)) time complexity (n being the length of the pattern). However with the implementation above, the time complexity seems to be O(mk.log(n)) (m being the length of the text). I have browsed several solutions and noticed that there is also an outer loop of (m - n) times, thus should have a factor of m. Then how could I reduce the runtime to O(nk.log(n))?

I suspect a typo in the claim about the solution time for this problem.  At minimum, you have to have O(m) in there, because you have to read the whole input.

@LouisWasserman I want to say so, but the grader for this problem keeps rejecting my solution, saying it exceeds the time limit, so I suspect some parts can still be improved
